# Gurobi constraints and objective function

Tags: linear-programming, gurobi

I am very new to `Gurobi`.  I am trying to solve the following `ILP`

> minimize \sum_i c_i y_i + \sum_i \sum_j D_{ij} x_{ij}

Here `D` is stored as a `2D numpy array`.
My constraints are as follows

> x_{ij} <= y_i
>   y_i + \sum_j x_{ij} = 1

Here's the image of the algebra :

[image]

My code so far is as follows,

```
from gurobipy import *

def gurobi(D,c):
    n = D.shape[0]
    m = Model()
    X = m.addVars(n,n,vtype=GRB.BINARY)
    y = m.addVars(n,vtype=GRB.BINARY)   

    m.update()

    for j in range(D.shape[0]):
        for i in range(D.shape[0]):
            m.addConstr(X[i,j] <= y[i])
```

I am not sure about, how to implement the second constraint and specify the objective function, as objective terms includes a numpy array. Any help ?

Comment: I attached an image of the rendered latex, because SO does not support latex syntax ;)

Comment: which version of Gurobi are you using ?

Comment: @digEmAll 8.1.1

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I don't have GUROBI because it's really expensive...

but, according to [this tutorial](https://www.gurobi.com/resource/modeling-with-the-gurobi-python-interface/) the second constraint should be implemented like this :

```
for i in range(n):
    m.addConstr(y[i] + quicksum(X[i,j] for j in range(n), i) == 1)
```

while the objective function can be defined as :

```
m.setObjective(quicksum(c[i]*y[i] for i in range(n)) + quicksum(quicksum(D[i,j] * x[i,j]) for i in range(n) for j in range(n)), GRB.MINIMIZE)
```

N.B: I'm assuming `D` is a matrix `n x n`

Answer (score 1):

This is a very simple case. You can write the first constraint this way. It is a good habit to name your constraints.

```
m.addConstrs((x[i,j] <= y[j] for i in range(D.shape[0]) for j in range(D.shape[0])), name='something')
```

If you want to add  the second constraint, you can write it like this

```
m.addConstrs((y[i] + x.sum(i, '*') <= 1 for i in range(n)), name='something')
```

you could write the second equations ass well using quicksum as suggested by digEmAll. 
The advantage of using `quicksum` is that you can add `if` condition so that you don't um over all values of `j`. Here is how you could do it

```
m.addConstrs((y[i] + quicksum(x[i, j] for j in range(n)) <= 1 for i in range(n)), name='something')
```

if you only needed some values of j to sum over then you could:

```
m.addConstrs((y[i] + quicksum(x[i, j] for j in range(n) if j condition)  <= 1 for i in range(n)), name='something')
```

I hope this helps